# How can I get Selenium to operate directly on an existing Firefox profile?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I've discovered that even if I specify:

```
webdriver.Firefox(
    firefox_profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile("/my/profile/path")
)
```

Selenium actually *clones* that profile and launches the browser based on that temporary clone.  I'm sure this makes sense when you're using Selenium for testing, but as I'm using it for automation, I'd like to operate directly on the existing profile.

Is this possible with Selenium?  Really I'm looking for a way to maintain state between sessions (bookmarks, history, Firefox sync setup, etc.) so a persistent session makes the most sense to me.  I'm doing this work in Python, but I imagine that the pattern used in other languages would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from selenium import webdriver

myprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\{YOUR OWN USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\moskcpdq.SeleniumTest')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=myprofile, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Make sure you are using the correct path for the profile!

Comment: Unfortunately, this *appears* to work, but what's really going on is that Selenium *copies your entire profile into a temp directory*, uses that directory for the entire run and then deletes everything when it shuts down -- losing any history generated.